# hardware to monitor if power is available

Tags: monitoring, electrical-power

Our server-cage is working on 3-phase power. I had this week this unpleasant surprise that one of 3 fuses went off. Can somebody advise me on some (simple) schematics that would allowed me to check on-line what happens to all three phases. I would prefer USB solution (plenty of this on board).

thanks in advance, kris

Comment: Usb is wrong  you woukd want a 3 pase pdu with montioring via snmp over network. More reliable

Answer (score 1):

This product would appear to do the trick:

http://www.currentcost.net/monitor.html
http://www.currentcost.net/Threephaseinstallations.html

Whether this is the right choice for your environment, I can't say.  One question is how you handle monitoring in general-- if you have a system monitoring solution in place, you'd want sensor devices that can talk to your system monitoring solution.

If you don't have a system monitoring solution in place, I'd suggest looking into getting one.  It's an early step toward avoiding unpleasant suprises about the status of servers in a datacenter environment.